# Servlet :unknown source

Tags: servlets, nullpointerexception

I have this code in my servlet. when i run it on server,  i have this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)**

My part of code:

```
String datenaiss = request.getParameter("datenaiss");

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

try {
    cl.setDatenaiss((Date) formatter.parse(datenaiss));
} catch (ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("date error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of Locale. you can try

```
Locale locale = new Locale("US");
```

and put that 'locale' variable into my SimpleDateFormat constructor.
This might resolve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean i have to put "local" instead of "yyyy-mm-dd"??  if it's so, it didn't accept it...

Comment: String pattern = "EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("en", "US"));

String date = sdFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);

like this. Or can you post your whole code so I can identify your issue in better way